# How to generate anti-forgery token in objective C to validate with server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asp.net-mvc, xss, antiforgerytoken

In order to prevent cross-site request forgery attacks, We have used **ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute attribute** provided in **asp.net mvc2** by annotating the method with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`. For the HTML views, generating and supplying the token is easy as following.

```
<%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
```

However request from client applications to server to the same controller method fails as it does not have token included in its header. For the requests that are generated from mobile client (iPad / iPhone), how can anti-forgery token be generated in when requesting? Do any inbuilt classes or third party libraries available in `Objective-C`?